# Add new label and textfield on button click Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I have this code with three buttons. I want to add a label and a textfield after a buttonclick. So for the 'button' I want to add the 'label' and 'textfield.

For 'button2' I want to add 'label2' and 'textfield2'. And so on.

I already have this code, but it isn't working. I also don't understand how I can create three different ActionListeners.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    private JTextField textfield3;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Interface();
    }

    public Interface()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10,10,600,600);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("Button 1");
        label.setBounds(5,5,600,20);

        label2 = new JLabel("Button 2");
        label2.setBounds(5,5,600,20);

        label3 = new JLabel("Button 3");
        label3.setBounds(5,5,600,20);

        textfield = new JTextField();
        textfield.setBounds(5,30,100,20);

        JButton button = new JButton("cirkel");
        button.setBounds(130,30,100,20);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("driehoek");
        button2.setBounds(250,30,100,20);
        button2.addActionListener(this);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("vierhoek");
        button3.setBounds(370,30,100,20);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(textfield);
            panel.validate();
            panel.repaint();
            String text = textfield.getText();

            // Van de String 'text' een double maken
            double diameter = Double.parseDouble(text);

            cirkel C1 = new cirkel();
            C1.setDiam(diameter);
            label.setText("De diameter = " + C1.getDiam() + " cm \n\n");
            label.setText("De straal = " + C1.getRadius() + " cm");
            label.setText("De oppervlakte van de cirkel = " + C1.berekenOpp() + " cm2");

    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @MadProgrammer is that the reason this code isn't working? I'm new to Java so I don't completely understand it...

Comment: It's going to be a factor

Comment: `Interface` isn't the best name for a class. Moving along, your design currently assigns the same ActionListener  (this) to all three buttons, so they'll all do the same thing. Both answers below should be considered, as they point you to resources that explain how to create unique ActionListeners for a component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few choices:

## You could...

Create a `ActionListener` for each button, this can be done using a outer, inner or anonymous class, this means that you provide a self contained unit of work for each button which is related to only that button.

You could also take advantage of the `Action` API for the same reasons. See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

## You could...

Check the `ActionEvent#getSource` property and compare it to an instance of the button, but your buttons are defined locally

## You could...

Use the `actionCommand` property of the buttons, setting each button a unique "command" which you can use the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` to compare with when the `ActionListener` is triggered

Regardless of which choice you use, have a closer look at
[How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

## Example

Now, having had a chance to run your code, you have a `NullPointerException` because `panel` is `null` in the context of the `ActionListener`.  This is cased by the fact that you are shadowing the variable (declaring it twice)

```
// Declared here
private JPanel panel;

public Interface() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    // And here...
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

So, instead, you could use a anonymous class for each button...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Interface {

    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    private JTextField textfield3;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Interface();
    }

    public Interface() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("Button 1");
        label2 = new JLabel("Button 2");
        label3 = new JLabel("Button 3");

        textfield = new JTextField(5);

        JButton button = new JButton("cirkel");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.add(label);
                panel.add(textfield);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                String text = textfield.getText();

                // Van de String 'text' een double maken
                double diameter = Double.parseDouble(text);

//      cirkel C1 = new cirkel();
//      C1.setDiam(diameter);
                label.setText("De diameter = " + 1 + " cm \n\n");
                label.setText("De straal = " + 2 + " cm");
                label.setText("De oppervlakte van de cirkel = " + 3 + " cm2");
            }
        });

        JButton button2 = new JButton("driehoek");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.add(label);
                panel.add(textfield);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                // driehoek
            }
        });

        JButton button3 = new JButton("vierhoek");
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.add(label);
                panel.add(textfield);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                // vierhoek
            }
        });

        buttonPane.add(button);
        buttonPane.add(button2);
        buttonPane.add(button3);

        panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The next problem you'll have is a `NumberFormatException`, because you
you're trying to convert a blank `String` to a `double`, because there is nothing in the text field yet...

Comment: Can you please give me a little example of the first option. Because I don't understand why my current code isn't working in the first place. Just for one button only..

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still get an error if I click any button:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Interface.actionPerformed(Interface.java:68)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you remember to add `panel = new JPanel();` in the constructor like the demo?

Comment: Yep (if I take out `double diameter = Double.parseDouble(text);`) it works just fine.

Comment: I have copied your second code, and added the 'panel = new JPanel();' in the constructor,  and took out double diameter

Comment: Try copying the demo code in it's entirety and running it

Comment: I copied the whole code that comes after 'So, instead, you could use a anonymous class for each button...' 
Added 'panel = new JPanel();' and removed double diameter

Comment: Mustn't I implement ActionListener after the public class?

Comment: No, that's what the anonymous classes are doing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create three different ActionListeners, you can create three inner classes, and implement an ActionListener to each class. and put the instance of the class inside the `addActionListener()`.

```
public class Example {

    ActionListen listen = new ActionListen();

    button.addActionListener(listen);

    private class ActionListen implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //code here to change...
        }
    }
}
```